# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called When implemneting Collapsable TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Everything is ok, but why is `didselect` not being called

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{
self.tableView.dataSource=self;

self.tableView.delegate=self;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"did select row not called**strong text**");
}
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but you have to call `super` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: call but nothing happen

Comment: i think you want expand/collaps your cell as per click on cell. right ?

Comment: yes its working

Comment: what fixed the issue post it as answer and accept

Comment: already post answer

Answer (score 1):

**Reason to add these two lines in viewDidLoad is that when  use gesture UIGestureRecognizer 
then didSelectRowAtIndexPath not work after adding these line its work**

`self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;`

`self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad

    {
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;

    self.tableView.delegate=self;

    self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;

    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"did select row being called");
}
```